# Python Dictionary and Tuples Addition

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, counting

Need a bit of help on this problem:

I have the following code:

```
def insertIntoDataStruct(state,job,count,dict):
    if not state in dict:
        print "adding"
        dict[state] = [(job,count)]
    else:
        for x in range(0, len(dict[state])):
            if(dict[state][x][0] == job):
                print "hi"
                print dict[state][x][0]
                print job
                print state
                print dict[state][x][1]
                dict[state][x][1] = dict[state][x][1] + 1
            else:
                dict[state].append((job,count))

courses = {}

insertIntoDataStruct("CA", "2121", (1), courses)
insertIntoDataStruct("CA", "169521", 1, courses)
insertIntoDataStruct("CA", "2121", 1, courses)
insertIntoDataStruct("TX", "2121", 1, courses)
insertIntoDataStruct("TX", "169521", 1, courses)
insertIntoDataStruct("TX", "262420", 1, courses)

print courses
```

and I am getting this error:

```
adding File "test2.py", line 21, in <module>
hi
insertIntoDataStruct("CA", "2121", 1, courses)
2121
File "test2.py", line 13, in insertIntoDataStruct
2121
dict[state][x][1] = dict[state][x][1] + 1
CA
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I go about fixing : TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

The Ideal output of this code should be:

```
{
'CA': [('2121', 2), ('169521', 1), ('2122', 1)], 
'TX': [('2121', 1), ('169521', 1), ('262420', 1)]
}
```

Thanks for all help!

Comment: `[(job,count)]` is a tuple inside a list. Tuples are immutable, i.e. they can't be altered. On line 13, it appears that you're trying to change the value inside the tuple. You might want to check out `collections` for incrementing counters: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tuple`s are immutable. Therefore, when you try to run the line `dict[state][x][1] = dict[state][x][1] + 1`, where the left side is the tuple `('2121', 1)`, the `'tuple' object does not support item assignment` error results.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict[state][x][1] = dict[state][x][1] + 1
```

You cannot do item assignment here.
My understanding is you want to increment the job ID and add the course in the dictionary with the new job, what you can do is

```
new_job = str(int(dict[state][x][1])+1)
dict[state].append((new_job, count))
```

Here I have incremented the job and then appended into the dictionary